# In IE7 position relative showing on top of position absolute?

Tags: html, css

In my following code, why is the second textbox showing above the div?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:relative;width: 170px;height: 50px;">
            <input type="text"  />
            <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 999999;border: 1px solid;background:#D1C9AF;left:0;top:30px;">
                demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1
                demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1
                demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1 demo text div1
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div style="position:relative;width: 170px;height: 50px;">
            <input type="text"  />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've set `position: absolute` on your `div`. This takes the element out of the page flow and means elements around it will ignore the space it would have taken up.

Here's some [further reading on CSS positioning](http://css-tricks.com/1191-absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Answer (score 0):

relative is always with higher z-index in IE7, you can simply remove position relative from those two divs or place absolute into relative with higher z-index that those two.